# Съезжает элемент в CSS

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce

при выборе вариативного товара в woocommerce, надпись очистить неправильно отображается, плывет
https://apphone.ru/product/iphone-xs-max-512gb-zolotoj/
хотя вот на этом товаре все в норме
https://apphone.ru/product/iphone-se-128gb-zolotoj/

что изменить чтобы в первом случае надпись отображалась корректно?

Answer (score 2):

Позиционирование даннного элемента сделано абсолютом.
Относительно какого элемента будет применятся свойство top right bottom left, зависит от того, у какого ближайшего из родительских элементов прописано свойство position: relative;
Так как твой ближайший блок (по уровням вложености) это tbody, то все элементы которые находятся внутри него и имеют абсолютное позиционирование, будут "прилипать" к границам этого блока.
У tbody не стоит фиксированая ширина, поэтому его ширина формируется в зависимости от контента.
Так как элементы с абсолютным позиционированием не участвуют в определении размеров блока, тебе нужно прописать статичную ширину (или минимальную ширину) блоку tbody.
Например:

```css
tbody {
    min-width: 240px;
}
```

Comment: спасибо тебе, помогло)

Comment: you are welcome!